# Problems with A.N.T. landscape. doesnt edit

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, error

when adding the landscape mesh it shows an error (shown in image) and doesn't let me edit the landscape I added with the side menu. I already reinstalled blender and it didn't work, any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using? Did you add the landscape through Add -> Mesh -> Landscape? Remember that as of blender 2.79, you don't have to install it using a separate file, blender already has it in its optional addons with the compatible version.

For that you can go to user preferences -> add-ons and search for A.N.T and activate it like this:
[image]

Ps. I had some trouble when i was first starting out and downloaded the addon from a previous version, causing compatibility problems.

As described [here](https://developer.blender.org/T53537) you could  try:

1 -close blender

2 - rename C:\Users\yournamehere\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79 
  to
   C:\Users\yournamehere\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79.bak

start blender, should be good as new now.

Remember to always download from the official blender site, blender.org

Comment: I’m using blender 2.79 and I added the landscape through add->mesh->landscapes but after I add it it shows the error. Also any add on I used I added through user preferences.

Comment: Have you tried resetting to factory settings? You might have corrupted your user preferences with some addon, you could try what i edited in the comment above

Comment: Thank you, I reseted to factory settings and it works now.

Comment: @Kirill Awesome! Could you mark the question as solved? It might people with the same problem in the future